# APDU commands, error trying to digitally sign

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I'm working with smart cards and APDU commands.
I am trying to digitally sign a hash with the private key inside my card.
Following some tutorials, I am executing the following script but the last one gives me an error.

```
00 20 00 81 06 3x 3x 3x 3x 3x 3x  --VERIFY response: 9000
00 A4 04 00 XX xx xx xx xx xx xx.....  --SELECT APP response: 9000
00 22 41 B6 06 80 01 8A 84 01 81  --SECURITY ENVIRONMENT response: 9000
00 2A 9E 9A XX xx xx xx xx xx xx.....  --SIGN  response: 6a88
```

In the last command, the expected response would be: **HASH_SIGNED + 9000**. But it is responding: **6a88**.

Could someone help me, what may be wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's "reference data not found", there are plenty of APDU status words lists on the internet. So the reference in the parameters isn't correct, the private key that you try to access doesn't seem to exist. If this is an ISO 7816-15 compatible card then you should try and read out the data structures on it to find out where the objects reside. Smart cards are really small computers (SoC's) so they can be programmed in *any* way and contain any object.

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, thank you very much for your reply. I totally understand, in this case there will be some way to explore the structure of the card as I don't have documentation.